# AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am  getting following error when tried to create topic for amazon sns messaging.
    The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: OptInRequired; Request ID: 9b0bd34b-6ebd-5ece-a78d-8013adb25940)

[image]

Comment: I have also created IAM user and subscribed for the SNS service but getting same error.

Comment: Hi please check the permissions of the IAM user

Comment: IAM user have all permission

Comment: i added debit card in aws account

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that your account is new and payment mode is still not verified by Amazon. Please re-check and try to contact with their support.

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Sns\SnsClient' not found in E:\wamp\www\sms.php on line 22